# what is the probability of one of the horses winning the race?

Tags: probability

Probability of horse $A$ winning is $\frac{1}{4}$ and probability of horse $B$ winning in the same race is $\frac{1}{6}$. what is the probability of one of them winning?

Comment: Are the horses winning independent events?

Comment: What work have you done on this?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $$P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
What is $P(A \cap B)$?